# Loop condition works well with raw iterator but not with iterator dereferencing

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop, iterator

In the snippet below,
`while(litr < = ritr)` works well, but  `while(*litr < *ritr)` can not be met and goes out of range and crashes when try to search element which is not present in vector. **I understand, loop will work with raw iterators but Why loop condition can not be met with iterator dereference**?

```
bool binarySearch(std::vector<int> sorted_list, int item)
{
    if(sorted_list.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    auto litr = sorted_list.begin();
    auto ritr = sorted_list.end()-1;

    while(litr <= ritr)
    {
        int leftindex = std::distance(sorted_list.begin(), litr);
        int rightindex = std::distance(sorted_list.begin(), ritr);

        int mid = (leftindex + ((rightindex-leftindex)/2));

        if(sorted_list.at(mid) == item)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(item < sorted_list.at(mid))
        {
            ritr = sorted_list.begin() + mid-1;
        }
        else
        {
            litr = sorted_list.begin()+ mid+1;

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hello. On one hand you want to iterate other all of the items of the vector `while(litr <= ritr)`. On the other hand you create a condition that depends on the actual vectors values `while(*litr < *ritr)`. What makes you think the second version would work? It is dependent on vector values them selves. I'm not surprise this can end badly. The conditions are not at all equivalent.

Comment: What do you think a deduction mean? Do you mean dereferencing? And like Jean-Marc commented, `while(litr <= ritr)` is nothing similar to `while(*litr < *ritr)`

Comment: If item is smaller than the smallest item in the sorted_list, the function will crash because ritr will go out of the range of sorted_list. You have to put in a check at the beginning for that possibility.

Comment: Thanks. Was more focused on the dereferencing part. So just pasted code without testing. But I get it now, why dereferece won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "iterator deduction". I think you mean "dereferencing"?

Anyway, you're asking about `while(litr <= ritr)` (which works) compared to `while(*litr < *ritr)` (which fails). There are several differences.

### LessThanOrEqual vs. Equal

The working code uses `<=` rather than just `<`, and the equals part is necessary for correct operation.

Consider a sequence of just three elements (0, 10, 20), and the search item is 20. Then leftindex = 0, mid = 1, rightindex = 2. The search item is greater than mid, so the next index values are leftindex = 2, rightindex = 2. If there is no equals in the comparison, the loop ends here, and the function returns false, which is incorrect. The loop condition must be `<=` so that the loop executes again and the item is found.

### Iterator Comparison vs. Dereferencing the Iterators

When using `<=` for the loop condition, dereferencing the end() iterator is a problem in some cases.

Consider a sequence of just two elements (0, 10), and the search item is 20. Then leftindex = 0, mid = 0, rightindex = 1. The search item is greater than mid, so the next values are leftindex = 1, rightindex = 1. On this loop, the search item is still greater than mid, so the next values are leftindex = 2, rightindex = 1. Note that leftindex is 2, which is equal to end(). If the loop condition uses `litr <= ritr`, this is OK. But if the loop condition uses `*litr <= *ritr`, the attempt to dereference the end iterator is undefined behavior.

### Iterator before begin()

Similar to above, consider a sequence of just two elements (0, 10), and the search item is -10. Then leftindex = 0, mid = 0, rightindex = 1. The search item is less than mid, so the next values are leftindex = 0, rightindex = -1. Just setting the iterator to this value is undefined behavior. Obviously dereferencing it is also undefined behavior.

Note that even your "working" variation `while(litr <= ritr)` has this problem. You will need some other code to prevent this.

### Other

Your code does `auto ritr = sorted_list.end()-1;`, so it assumes that there are is at least one element in the sorted list. You should modify the code to handle the case of an empty list.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. Took care of the empty list part. However, I was more focused on the dereferencing part and pasted the code without much testing.